# Seeing only NAN when using grid data to plot contour

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I am trying to get a 2D contour map of ten points

I tried to use griddata to generate my grid, however it does not seem to work and i only see NAN in my interpolated grid.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
xi = np.linspace(0,7500.0,100)
yi = np.linspace(0,7500.0,100)

indie_coords_y=[195,695,1195,1695,2195,2695,3195,3695,4195,4695]
indie_coords_x=[87,90,92,95,97,100,103,105,107,110]

z1_final=[12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21]

zi = griddata((indie_coords_x, indie_coords_y), z1_final, (xi[None,:], 
yi[:,None]), method='linear')
CS = plt.contourf(xi,yi,zi,cmap='jet', vmin=min(z1_final), 
vmax=max(z1_final))
```

When i use the above code i see that my zi array has just NAN values, whereas i would expect to see some contours

Can any one please help

Comment: the points `(indie_coords_x, indie_coords_y)` are almost on a line, They are not uniformly distributed over a surface... for this the 2D interpolation is not working, Could you give more details about what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the input data (shuffle `indie_coords_y`).
Also, th interpolation have to be performed for all the points of a grid. [`np.meshgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) is used to construct the full grid. [`.flatten()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) is used to convert the grid to a list of points (i.e. an array of shape number_of_points x number_of_dim). After the interpolation, `reshape` is used to convert the list of points back to a grid (two n by n arrays).

Now the interpolation and the graph are working:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

# Data
indie_coords_y = [195, 2195, 3195, 2695, 3695, 4695, 695, 1195, 1695, 4195] # Modified! 
# using np.random.shuffle(indie_coords_y)
indie_coords_x = [87,90,92,95,97,100,103,105,107,110]

z1_final = [12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21]

# Interpolation
xi = np.linspace(80, 120.0, 30)  # modified range
yi = np.linspace(0, 5000.0, 30)

X_grid, Y_grid = np.meshgrid(xi, yi) # Create a grid (i.e. 100x100 arrays)

zi = griddata((indie_coords_x, indie_coords_y), z1_final,
              (X_grid.flatten(), Y_grid.flatten()), method='linear')

Z_grid = zi.reshape( X_grid.shape )

# Graph
CS = plt.contourf(X_grid, Y_grid, Z_grid, cmap='jet')

plt.plot(indie_coords_x, indie_coords_y, 'ko', label='data points')
plt.plot(X_grid.flatten(), Y_grid.flatten(), 'r,', label='interpolation points')
plt.xlabel('x'); plt.ylabel('y');
plt.colorbar(); plt.legend();
```

the graph is:

[image: graph]